# magento 2: How to use the order by and limit clause in sql query

Tags: magento2, database, collection

I am using following code to filter result and i want to limit the result.

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection();
$giftColletion->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
$giftColletion->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

Comment: Did you try this $giftColletion->setPageSize(3)

Comment: Will try it, It will result me 3 records, right?

Comment: Yes you need to set count

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use setPageSize() to use limit in collection

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection();
$giftColletion->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
$giftColletion->setOrder('position','ASC');
$giftColletion->setOrder('salary','ASC');
$giftColletion->setPageSize(10);
```

Comment: You can change here 10 to your limit in setpagesize field. please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: how can i set order for two data fields like position and salary.

Comment: you can use two times setOrder()

Comment: you can also try with $giftCollection->setOrder(array('position', 'salary'), asc) if both are in asc order. Above is used for different sort order.

Comment: You can use multiple time setOrder() in your collection to sort field from collection.

Comment: let try with solutions and let me know if you have any query

Comment: hi please check this is not working :$collection->getSelect()->having('distance < '.$redious)->order('distance ASC');
        
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $collection->setCurPage($page);

Comment: HIIII ITS working now=>>> $collection->getSelect()->having('distance < '.$redious)->order('distance ASC')->limit($pageSize, $page);

Answer (score 2):

Using Page size you can set limit:

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection();
    $giftColletion->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
    $giftColletion->setOrder('position','ASC');
    $giftColletion->setPageSize($pageSize);
    $giftColletion->setCurPage($page);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
$giftColletion->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
$giftColletion->setOrder('attribute_code', 'ASC'); 
$giftColletion->setPageSize($limitNo);
```

Comment: I am looking for fetch product as per attribute value 1,2,3,4 not is ASC.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use the following but `setPageSize()` is also valid:

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit($limit);
```

Regarding sorting, if the direction of your sorting is the same for all fields, you can set that in just one call using an array:

```
$collection->setOrder([$field1, $field2, ...], $dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by :

```
$giftColletion->setOrder('position','ASC');
$giftColletion->setOrder('store_id','ASC');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code.

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection();
$giftColletion->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1)->setPageSize($limit)->setCurPage($criteria)->setOrder('position','ASC');
```